# How to change the default button color scheme throughout Xamarin Forms Prism application on iOS using Visual Material?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am using the [new Xamarin Forms Material Visual renderers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/visual/material-visual) for iOS with Xamarin Forms.  How do I change the color scheme, particularly button colors, used throughout the application?

I have tried this in my `app.xaml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<prism:PrismApplication xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Autofac;assembly=Prism.Autofac.Forms"
             x:Class="MyAppName.App">

 <prism:PrismApplication.Resources>   
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green" />
        </Style>
    </ResourceDictionary>
  </prism:PrismApplication.Resources>
</prism:PrismApplication>
```

But I'm still getting black buttons.

Here's the relevant parts of my AppDelegate.cs

```cs
namespace MyAppName.iOS
{
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public partial class AppDelegate : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.BarTintColor = UIColor.FromRGB(43, 132, 211); //bar background
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.TintColor = UIColor.White; //Tint color of button items
            UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(new UITextAttributes()
            {
                Font = UIFont.FromName("HelveticaNeue-Light", (nfloat)20f),
                TextColor = UIColor.White
            });

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.SetFlags("Visual");
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init();
            global::Xamarin.Forms.FormsMaterial.Init();

            LoadApplication(new App(new iOSInitializer()));

            return base.FinishedLaunching(app, options);
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the relevant parts of the code behind (I'm omitting type registration and some other methods):

```cs
[assembly: XamlCompilation(XamlCompilationOptions.Compile)]
namespace MyAppName
{
    public partial class App : PrismApplication
    {
        public App() : this(null) { }

        public App(IPlatformInitializer initializer) : base(initializer) { }

        protected override async void OnInitialized()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            BlobCache.ApplicationName = "My Application";
            await NavigationService.NavigateAsync("LoginPage");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Define the Global Styles  targeting the "Button" element with all the visuals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your App.XAML define the Style targeting the button with required visuals.

```
<Application>
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>

            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="12" />
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green" />
                <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="White" />
            </Style>

        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

It should automatically get applied throughout the app for all the buttons. All buttons will be green with white text! Hope this helps you.

**Update:**

```
<prism:PrismApplication xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Autofac;assembly=Prism.Autofac.Forms"
         x:Class="MyAppName.App">

<prism:PrismApplication.Resources>   
<ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Green" />
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
</prism:PrismApplication.Resources>
```

Comment: Thanks for this--I have edited my question to show my app.xaml, but I'm still getting black buttons.  Does this styling still work with the new Visual="Material" renderers?  Or maybe I have something wrong with my namespaces for Prism?

Comment: How your AppDelegate and MainActivity looks like? From what you are inheriting from?

Comment: Just edited question.  I should mention this is the iOS side I'm working on.

Comment: Could you try the new update inside your <PrismApplication>. Dont use <prism:PrismApplication.Resources> but <Application.Resources>

Comment: I take it all back it was your solution that worked.  I was having some trouble with VS not rebuilding the project when I thought it was... sorry!  I did have to include the prism namespaces:  

 <prism:PrismApplication.Resources>   
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="#1976d2" />
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
  </prism:PrismApplication.Resources>
</prism:PrismApplication> . If you want to put those namespaces back into your solution, I'll be sure to accept it.  Thanks!